# Django renders <head> in <body>

Tags: django

I have an small test scenario here because my main project has a strange bug. It renders my content from  tag in body tag and I coudnt find out whats the problem is.

layout.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Test-->
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                {% include 'app/loginpartial.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; {{ year }} - My Django Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/respond.js' %}"></script>
{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```html
{% extends "backend/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}Test{% endblock %}
```

Output:

```html
<html><head></head><body style="">


    
        <!--Test-->
    


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                
<form id="logoutForm" action="/logout/" method="post" class="navbar-right">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="pVxWYntPq9xRYYTxwvm44i9QHAooOClw4BwobLx9oVbtbpRSbNqPVnBZD20AKSIw">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><span class="navbar-brand">Hello westcoast-dk!</span></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
Test
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>© 2019 - My Django Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/static/app/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app/scripts/respond.js"></script>




</body></html>
```

What did I wrong? The layout is mostly copied from example files. Same what I do it renders always in this strange output.

PS I mean just the  text in head tag not in Body tag.

regards
Christopher.

Comment: What is the problem here?  "Test" seems to appear in the right place.

Comment: Its out of head tag, tag is closed

Comment: So your question is about the HTML-Comment "Test" - no the content block that is filled with "Test", I see now.  You should edit the question to make this clear at the beginning and avoid using "Test" in two places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Visual Studio 2019 - I add Advance Save options and change from UTF8 to Unicode 1250 and now it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2019